# Cannot return array when working with firestore snapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a messaging app using reactjs and firestore, when trying to get a snapshot of multiple users to return as an array to a reducer i could print it out but returning it yields "undefined"

This is my first question so i apologise if there is a lack of detail and i will happy to provide more if so

Snapshot code:

```
export const getFriends = createAsyncThunk(
  "friends/getFriends",

  async () => {
    try {
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        collection(db, "users"),
        (QuerySnapshot) => {
          const friend = [];
          QuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            friend.push(doc.data());
          });
          return friend;
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

Reducers code:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getFriends.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getFriends.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.friend = action.payload;
        console.log(action);
      })
      .addCase(getFriends.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
  },
```

[image: action.payload is undefined, should be an array]

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Firebase/firestore has a function called [getDocs()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getdoc).

It executes the query that returns a results as a QuerySnapshot.

**Note**: getDocs() attempts to provide up-to-date data when possible by waiting for data from the server, but it may return cached data or fail if you are offline and the server cannot be reached. To specify this behavior, invoke getDocsFromCache() or getDocsFromServer().

The problem in this code is that you are returning a value from a callback funcion that is not being used as a return value by any other functions. the `onSnapshot()` function is a asynchronous and returns a function to unsubscribe from the listener itself, but it does not return any value you are trying to get.

To solve this problem you can use the `asynch/await` to wait the data to be fetched before returning it to the reducer.

This code provides you for a better solution:

```
export const getFriends = createAsyncThunk(
  "friends/getFriends",

  async () => {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
      const friend = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        friend.push(doc.data());
      });
      return friend;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

In this code. The `getDocs()` function is fetching the data from firestore, and `await` is being used to wait for the data to be returned before processing it and returning it to the reducer.

**Reminder** : You can use the [onSnapshot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#onsnapshot_4) function for real-time changes. You have to pass a callback function to it that updates the state in your component, not your thunk.

Hope it helps.